# Simple regex in python to filter out one word

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have the output as

```
app_39    281   33    94332  21228 ffffffff afd0c51c S abc
app_39    292   33    103864 30060 ffffffff afd0c51c S cvc.notes
app_39    303   33    94332  21344 ffffffff afd0c51c S cocccs:syncHandler
app_39    312   33    94332  21404 ffffffff afd0c51c S cccs:cacheHandler
app_39    321   33    94332  21344 ffffffff afd0c51c S cocccs:dailyReceiver
```

This whole output is stored in a variabble called outresult

How can I use python to extract the 2nd word of the second line? that is 292 and store it in a variable?

Comment: Do you have this output as a list? As a multiline string? As a file or a stream like `stdin`?

Comment: No, it is **not** STO-RED IN A VA-RIA-B-LE gna gna gna. There are **no** variables get out of it by Python. There are only identifiers and objects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
output.split('\n')[1].split()[1]
```

No regex needed.

Comment: No regex needed, and now you got 0 problems +1.

Comment: `.split(None, 2)[1]` may be slightly more efficient as you only actually require 2 splits to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
ss = '''app_39    281   33    94332  21228 ffffffff afd0c51c S abc
app_39    292   33    103864 30060 ffffffff afd0c51c S cvc.notes
app_39    303   33    94332  21344 ffffffff afd0c51c S cocccs:syncHandler
app_39    312   33    94332  21404 ffffffff afd0c51c S cccs:cacheHandler
app_39    321   33    94332  21344 ffffffff afd0c51c S cocccs:dailyReceiver'''

def lect(inp,nline,nw):
    gen = (xli.split() for i,xli in enumerate(inp.splitlines()) if i==nline-1)
    return gen.next()[nw-1]


print lect(ss,2,2)
```